# what does ^@ sign in .txt file suggest

Tags: python, linux, file, binaryfiles

I was concurrently manipulating a txt file (some r/w operation)with multiple processes. and I saw traces of special signs as ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ spreading across some lines now and then. What does this suggest? And under what circumstances will these symbols appear. Does it mean some binary contents were written in to, by mistake, where it should be text?

**UPDATE**
I read through the documentation. Some suggest it's due to newline issue on linux/windows platform, while others suggest it's because of big endian/small endian in a networked environment. The fact is I was running multiple processes in a networked filesystem and manipulate one common txt file. So I guess the encoding format might be the major reason. Anyone who can suggest how to avoid this issue? I don't want to edit files(like manually doing text substitution). A clean way of producing the right file without any null characters are preferred.

**UPDATE2**
This is the python pseudo code that implements my project. the fcntl.lockf thing is to lock the common manipulated file across multiple machines that run multiple process on it.

```
 while(manipulatedfile size is not 0):
           open(manipulatedfile, 'r+') as fh:
           fcntl.lockf(fh, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
           all_lines = fh.readlines()
           listing=all_lines[0:50] #get the first 50 lines
           rest_lines = all_lines[50:] # get remaining lines
           fh.seek(0)
           fh.truncate()
           fh.writelines(rest_lines) # write remaining lines back to file
           fcntl.lockf(fh, fcntl.LOCK_UN)
           listing = map(lambda s:s.strip(), listing)
           do_sth(listing)
```

**Thanks**

Answer (score 4):

In ASCII, `^@` is a binary zero (`NUL`) character.

Data containing `^@` between each ASCII character can sometimes be incorrectly translated from Unicode (4 bytes to a character) to ASCII (1 bytes to a character), or vice versa.

To remove the `^@` characters, run `vi file.txt`, and enter `:%s/` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd> `//g` and hit <kbd>↵ Return</kbd>.

See [this detailed article](http://www.skyprod.net/pub/HintsandTips/ASCIIendline/) for more information.

Comment: is there a cleaner way of avoiding null characters. I read/write the file within a process. so it's not elegant to open vi, and so some re substitution. How can I avoid generating null characters in the first place?

Comment: @Daniel How were you manipulating the file? What language etc?

Answer (score 2):

These are ["file holes"](http://linux.die.net/man/5/srec_binary) and contain null characters. The null character (or NUL char) has an ASCII code of 0 and appears as `^@` when viewed in `vi` or `less`.

I usually see these when I am nearly out of disk space and processes are trying to write to log files.

Comment: is there a way I can read the lines regardless of the ^@ sign that's standing between words? say a line goes "Hello ^@^@wor^@ld". Is it possible to extract the "hello world" from it in a programming way?.  will open the files as binary mode help?